# How to re-assemble disassembled code

Tags: assembly, binutils, disassembly

I have an old lib created by old binutils. I can't link this lib with my new binutils (there was a bug in the my old binutils that caused functions names to stay as they compiled (no prefix was added) instead of adding the prefix "_" e.g. function name foo should become _foo after compilation and after assembly should be __foo. My assembler got *foo and didn't add the "*" prefix to be __foo so I got linker errors). Anyway I decided to disassemble the lib and re-assemble it. Is there a simple way to do it ?
I tryed

```
objdump -d ./libgcc.a > libgcc.d
```

and than

```
as ./libgcc.d -o libgcc_new.o
```

but got a lot of errors... I know that there are a lot of information in the disassemble file that couldn't be parsed by the assembler. So, is there a flag to strip all the irrelevant information so assembly will work ?

Comment: Look at the output to `objdump -d`. It has all sorts of output to organize the object dump listing, including assembly line numbers, byte codes associated with instructions, identifying object dump headings, etc. These are things that an assembler doesn't understand. An assembler needs valid assembler directives and instructions.

Comment: so, is there a way/flag to get to get "good" disassemly code that can be assembly again ?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: [Why there are not any disassemblers that can generate re-assemblable asm code?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/why-there-are-not-any-disassemblers-that-can-generate-re-assemblable-asm-code).